# texmaker on OS X does not show CJK punctuations in editor

Tags: texmaker, punctuation

My environment:

- OS X 10.11.4
- Texmaker 4.5
- mactex from `brew cask install mactex`
- OS X builtin Chinese input method

I configured texmaker to use XeLaTeX + View PDF, SimSun as Font, UTF-8 as encoding.

What works: I can see all the Chinese character in the TexMaker editor. These characters look fine in the output PDF.

What does not: But whenever I type in punctuations, they appear in the editor as English punctuations, and output as so as well.

In Sublime Text, the punctuations work.

I guess this is a Texmaker problem.

Please help!

**UPDATE**

Tested with Texmaker 4.5 for Windows and it works fine with both regular Chinese characters and punctuation. So it's probably a Mac-only issue.

Comment: Have you tried [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/obtaining.html)? If I try to reproduce your problem, the output looks correct in the pdf (including punctuation).

Comment: Thanks, do you mean you have tried TeXShop and it worked for you or do you mean Texmaker's output looks already to you? Sorry I wasn't sure.

Comment: Sorry my comment wasn't clear. I meant the pdf generated using TeXmaker looked fine, although I had to change the font in order to see Chinese in the editor (initially I only saw boxes). I've never had such issues with TeXShop though, so I was suggesting you try that instead. TeXmaker may be the better option if you need cross-platform support though.